# I am having trouble using indirect to access a cell in a different Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I have 2 spreadsheets, Test1 and Test2. In Test2, Cell B2 I want to access a cell in test1.  I want to use the value in cell A1 (the value is test1) indirectly to access cell A2 in test1.  This is the formula I use and am getting a Formula Parse Error.  I have also included links to the test spreadsheets:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLuD8Y4ApxXc2Zt3osHkTTsdWBjpiOIXFSFOdslca_Q/edit#gid=194909829","INDIRECT($A1&""!$A$2"")")
```

Test1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLuD8Y4ApxXc2Zt3osHkTTsdWBjpiOIXFSFOdslca_Q/edit#gid=194909829

Test2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10TA2hEwiDc9g-9_V30TQImZsgJVzVA2WFZifmbdL0d4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to import to Test2 from Test1 **a range of cells** (`A1:A2`), the formula should be:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLuD8Y4ApxXc2Zt3osHkTTsdWBjpiOIXFSFOdslca_Q/edit", "Sheet2!A1:A2")
```

If on the other want to import **just a single cell** (`A1`) the formula would be:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLuD8Y4ApxXc2Zt3osHkTTsdWBjpiOIXFSFOdslca_Q/edit", "Sheet2!A"&"1")
```

#### Please pay attention on the second part of the formula:

- for a **range of cells**: `"Sheet2!A1:A2"`
- for a **single cell**: just `"Sheet2!A1"` OR `"Sheet2!A"&"1"`

There is no need to use `INDIRECT`
*(I must admit I am a bit confused about what you want)*

> #### EDIT
>
> *(following your clarifications in the comments)*

Instead of `INDIRECT` **you should use `INDEX`**.
This way your variables and formulas in e.g. cell `A9` of spreadsheet Test2 would be:

- for a **range of cells**: `WorkSheet2!A3:B7`
- for a **single cell**: just `WorkSheet2!A1`

In cell `B9` of spreadsheet Test2 use the formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1HLuD8Y4ApxXc2Zt3osHkTTsdWBjpiOIXFSFOdslca_Q/edit",""& INDEX(A9,,1) &"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated the Test1 and Test2 spreadsheets to try to be more clear in what I am trying to do.  In Test2, column A is a list of worksheets in Test1.  In column B I want to get the value of cell A2 from the Test1 worksheet listed in column A.  I hope that helps.

Comment: _"... "_ But... but... but... You did not even try the formula I gave you. I see you have **exactly** the same mistakes. e.g. instead of `"Sheet2!A1:A2"` ( or following your update `"WorkSheet2!A2"`) you still use `INDIRECT($A1&""!$A$2"")`. I believe no further explanations will work. Just try to understand the formula and test it. Then use similar ones for the rest of your WorkSheets. They will work for you. :)

Comment: I did try that and that did work - see cell B4 in the Test 2 spreadsheet.  But I don't want to hardcode Worksheet2 in the formula.  I want to pick that up (WorkSheet2) from Column A.

Comment: _"...I don't want to hardcode Worksheet2 in the formula."_ You do not hardcode it. This is just the way it is done. You mistakenly think that using `#gid=194909829` helps the formula. It does not. It is the `spreadsheet ID/edit` and the name of the sheet that make it work resulting to `value2`.

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Comment: Got it.   Thank you.  Index does what I need.

Comment: This is my first time asking in this forum.  I don't see what I need to do to accept the answer.  How do I accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

- all you need is this:

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("1HLuD8Y4ApxXc2Zt3osHkTTsdWBjpiOIXFSFOdslca_Q", A20)
  ```

  [image: 0]